# Select an element by class IF it has this particular data-attribute (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, button, jquery-selectors

Consider this HTML:

```
<button class="btn-edit"   data-user="joe">   Need to select this. </button>
<button class="btn-cancel" data-user="joe">   Not this. </button>
<button class="btn-edit"   data-user="sally"> Not this. </button>
<button class="btn-cancel" data-user="sally"> Not this. </button>
```

I'd like to select the first button - Joe's edit button.  Basically of all the edit buttons, I want to select the one that matches the data-attribute that I have.

I got this far:

```
$('[data-user="joe"]')
```

But that selected both the top two buttons.

Bonus points: "joe" comes in as a variable.  So I'm dealing with:

```
var userNameFromForm = "joe";
$('[data-user="'+userNameFromForm+'"]')
```

But that's nutty so I'll be happy with an answer to the original question, or suggestions on how best to refactor this if I'm off in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var userNameFromForm = "joe";

        //$('.btn-edit[data-user=' + userNameFromForm + ']') element that you want

        $('.btn-edit[data-user=' + userNameFromForm + ']').css('color', 'red')
```

Answer (score 4):

Add the class selector, `.btn-edit`, and then either use the [`:first` selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), or the [`.first()` method](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to select the first element in the jQuery object:

```
$('[data-user="joe"].btn-edit:first');
// or
$('[data-user="joe"].btn-edit').first();
```

The same applies to the version with the variable:

```
var userNameFromForm = "joe";

$('[data-user="' + userNameFromForm + '"].btn-edit:first');
// or
$('[data-user="' + userNameFromForm + '"].btn-edit').first();
```

Comment: Ah so as long as I can ensure that the Edit button is the first button in the HTML with that data-attribute, it will be the first in the jQuery selected set, so it will be accessible with :first or .first().  Brilliant!

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant that you always wanted to select the first button. If not, just combine the attribute/class selectors: `$('.btn-edit[data-user="joe"]:first')`

Answer (score 1):

As Josh Crozier mentioned, you could try using the `:first` selector, but I wouldn't recommend that unless you're certain the order of the buttons don't change. I'd probably recommend using more selectors or adding ID's to your buttons.

For instance, you can also target the class name `btn-edit` since I can see they're unique within your snippet:

```
$('.btn-edit[data-user="joe"]')
```

But the safest would be to use unique names as an ID attribute:

```
<button id="edit" class="btn-edit" data-user="joe"></button>

$('#edit')
```